# Embedding a live chart from an external page into Wordpress post

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress site has a blog on the homepage, e.g. www.myblog.com.
I made a web app in Flask (a Python web development framework) which has the url www.myblog.com:8000/chart1

I want to show this within a post on my homepage/blog. If this is possible how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An iframe should work. WordPress strips iframes out of the post editor, but you could either hardcode the `<iframe src="www.myblog.com:8000/chart1"></iframe>` HTML into a specific post type or something. I think a simpler option would be just to use a plugin like Iframe Shortcode:

[Iframe Shortcode](https://wordpress.org/plugins/flynsarmy-iframe-shortcode/)

Install/activate that and it'll give you an option to insert a shortcode into your post content.